# Implement Louvain in pyspark using dataframes

Tags: pyspark

I'm trying to implement the [Louvain algorihtm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Louvain_modularity) in pyspark using dataframes. The problem is that my implementation is reaaaally slow. This is how I do it:

1. I collect all vertices and communityIds into simple python lists
2. For each vertex - communityId pair I calculate the modularity gain using dataframes (just a fancy formula involving edge weights sums/differences)
3. Repeat untill no change

What am I doing wrong?

I suppose that if I could somehow parallelize the for each loop the performance would increase, but how can I do that?

**LATER EDIT:**
I could use `vertices.foreach(changeCommunityId)` instead of the for each loop, but then I'd have to compute the modularity gain (that fancy formula) without dataframes.

See the code sample below:

```
def louvain(self):

        oldModularity = 0 # since intially each node represents a community

        graph = self.graph

        # retrieve graph vertices and edges dataframes
        vertices = verticesDf = self.graph.vertices
        aij = edgesDf = self.graph.edges

        canOptimize = True

        allCommunityIds = [row['communityId'] for row in verticesDf.select('communityId').distinct().collect()]
        verticesIdsCommunityIds = [(row['id'], row['communityId']) for row in verticesDf.select('id', 'communityId').collect()]

        allEdgesSum = self.graph.edges.groupBy().sum('weight').collect()
        m = allEdgesSum[0]['sum(weight)']/2

        def computeModularityGain(vertexId, newCommunityId):

            # the sum of all weights of the edges within C
            sourceNodesNewCommunity = vertices.join(aij, vertices.id == aij.src) \
                                .select('weight', 'src', 'communityId') \
                                .where(vertices.communityId == newCommunityId);
            destinationNodesNewCommunity = vertices.join(aij, vertices.id == aij.dst) \
                                .select('weight', 'dst', 'communityId') \
                                .where(vertices.communityId == newCommunityId);

            k_in = sourceNodesNewCommunity.join(destinationNodesNewCommunity, sourceNodesNewCommunity.communityId == destinationNodesNewCommunity.communityId) \
                        .count()
            # the rest of the formula computation goes here, I just wanted to show you an example
            # just return some value for the modularity
            return 0.9  

        def changeCommunityId(vertexId, currentCommunityId):

            maxModularityGain = 0
            maxModularityGainCommunityId = None
            for newCommunityId in allCommunityIds:
                if (newCommunityId != currentCommunityId):
                    modularityGain = computeModularityGain(vertexId, newCommunityId)
                    if (modularityGain > maxModularityGain):
                        maxModularityGain = modularityGain
                        maxModularityGainCommunityId = newCommunityId

            if (maxModularityGain > 0):
                return maxModularityGainCommunityId
            return currentCommunityId

        while canOptimize:

            while self.changeInModularity:

                self.changeInModularity = False

                for vertexCommunityIdPair in verticesIdsCommunityIds:
                    vertexId = vertexCommunityIdPair[0]
                    currentCommunityId = vertexCommunityIdPair[1]
                    newCommunityId = changeCommunityId(vertexId, currentCommunityId)

                self.changeInModularity = False

            canOptimize = False
```

Comment: Have you considered using Graphframes instead of dataframes? There is a feature request for this here: https://github.com/graphframes/graphframes/issues/299 and there is an old version of Louvain modularity in scala and spark  GraphX implemented here: https://github.com/Sotera/spark-distributed-louvain-modularity

Comment: @HelloLili did you ever resolve this?  It could help me out a lot now.  Thanks!

Comment: @JohnSmith I managed to find a partial solution; you can compute the modularity gain without dataframes - since it is a very efficient formula (one of the reasons Louvain is so fast). Also, compute the modularity gain ONLY between each node and ITS NEIGHBORING communities (no need to match it to all the communities).

Comment: @HelloLili is this your latest code? I am interested in paying someone to commit an implementation of modularity to GraphFrames: http://graphframes.org/

Comment: Hello @HelloLili. Did you ever find a solution to this?
I currently have a working version of the algorithm, but it is also very slow. Is there any chance we could talk?

Comment: This is getting added to GraphFrames in a new implementation. See: https://github.com/graphframes/graphframes/issues/299

Answer (score 1):

As noted in a [Spark implementation](https://github.com/Sotera/spark-distributed-louvain-modularity) of the algorithm, the trick is to reassign all nodes simultaneously (rather than iteratively).

> In the distributed version all vertices make this choice simultaneously rather than in serial order, updating the graph state after each change. Because choices are made in parallel some choice will be incorrect and will not maximize modularity values, however after repeated iterations community choices become more stable and we get results that closely mirror the serial algorithm.

So `changeCommunityID()` should be mapped to all vertices simultaneously, or better yet, you can write a function that calculates the change in modularity caused by switching all the nodes to all their neighboring communities simultaneously (the algebra is a bit tough; just remember that double summations are essentially just a group by + sum).